# Linux Container - device-add not reflecting devices under /rootfs

Tags: linux, lxc

I shifted a setup I am running from one machine to another - and now, when I call 
`lxc-device add -n <NAME> /dev/bus/usb/###/###`, the device paths are no longer reflected under
`/var/lib/lxc/<NAME>/rootfs/dev/bus/usb/###/###`.

I'm not sure exactly what has changed - or what flags would affect this.